# unable to send mail through the from address in gmail

Tags: email-server, postfix

I am trying to send mail using postfix, I have set up all the things, the mail is going, I have set up the email using my domain i.e. `xyz@domain.com`. 
When When I am using the following code

```
ehlo xyz
mail from:<abc@gmail.com>
rcpt to:<pqe@gmail.com>
data
Subject:Test mail from postfix
```

This mail is going to inbox of pqe, but the sender address is xyz@domain.com, then what is the use of this `abc@gmail.com` or this mail from ?/

Answer (score 1):

Try out this :-

```
ehlo xyz
mail from:abc@gmail.com
rcpt to:pqe@gmail.com
data    
From:abc@gmail.com
To:pqe@gmail.com
Subject:Test mail from postfix

test
.
```

Comment: I have tried it out but this from and to section is sending as the body of mail

Comment: Its worked for me. Can you please tell me how did you send test mails ?

Answer (score 0):

That `from` header means that you will be telling the recipient mail server that this is the email where the message generated. However, that means that your `domain.com` must be listed in the SPF records of `gmail.com`, which I'm sure isn't the case. That usually means either being unable to send the email or ending up in the junk/spam folder.

Comment: If I have set this from address at abc@gmail.com then the reciever pqe@gmail.com should get the sender name as abc@gamil.com instead of xyz@domain.com